# How to clone and append empty element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to append empty html rows.

My desired result is to append html rows and remove its(appended row's) contents.

to achieve it,I apply `.html('')`method.

But it didn't work well.

My work is like below.

How can I append rows and remove its (appended rows) contents?

Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("table").on( "click", "tr", function() {
       $("table").append($(this).clone().html(' '));
   });
});
```

```css
table {
border-collapse:collapse;}

td {
border:solid black 1px;
transition-duration:0.5s;
padding: 5px;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: An empty `<tr>` doesn't have any representation, that's why you don't see them, but they are added. When you do `$(this).clone().html("")` you're clearing everything, including the `<td>`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply insert `tr` instead of cloning and removing its html?

```
$("table").on( "click", "tr", function() {
   $(this).after("<tr />");
});
```

If you want to clone `td` as well, then you can do:

```
$("table").on( "click", "tr", function() {
   var row = $(this).clone().find('td').html('');
   $(this).after(row);
});
```

If you want to append cloned element at the end of table, then you can do:

```
$("table").on( "click", "tr", function() {
   var row = $(this).clone().find('td').html('');
   row.appendTo('table');
});
```

Or even:

```
$('table').append(row)
```

To conclude on what you were doing wrong is emptying the cloned element instead of its `td` html.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table=$("table");
  table.on( "click", "tr", function() {
       var clonedTr=$(this).clone();
       clonedTr.find("td").html("");
       table.append(clonedTr);
   });
});
```

```css
table {
border-collapse:collapse;}

td {
border:solid black 1px;
transition-duration:0.5s;
padding: 5px;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#tableID').on( "click", "tr", function() {
    var elt = $(this).clone()
    elt.find('td').empty()
    $('#tableID').append(elt)
  })
});
```

```css
    table td {
      border: 1px solid;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```